# C# MSChart - charts area limits

Tags: c#, mschart

I have one Chart and three ChartArea that are aligned in view, zoom, cursor:
 [this is my related previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583912/c-sharp-how-to-align-two-or-more-charts-in-size-scroll-and-grid). All things works well except that the three ChartArea are not aligned at the beginning. Following an image of the problem:

[image: graphs example]

I think it depends from the digit's number of Y values axis. From some research I try the following configuration:

```
// selezione e zoom
dlChart.ChartAreas[VOLTAGE_AREA].CursorX.Interval = 1;
dlChart.ChartAreas[VOLTAGE_AREA].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
dlChart.ChartAreas[VOLTAGE_AREA].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
// generale
dlChart.ChartAreas[VOLTAGE_AREA].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yy - HH:mm:ss.fff";       
dlChart.ChartAreas[VOLTAGE_AREA].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
dlChart.ChartAreas[VOLTAGE_AREA].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "D5";
```

In witch the last row:

```
dlChart.ChartAreas[VOLTAGE_AREA].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "D5";
```

should specifies always five digits. This mitigate in some way the problem but it doesn't desappers. Furthermore with this row the program starts to throws very lots exceptions of form below any time I scroll the graph:

```
Generate exception: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Does anyone knows the solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately the axis labels are so smart they will trim normal white space.. One trick is to left-pad them with alt+255 spaces but with a proportional font you will still have various widths. Another trick is to reduce the ChartArea Size in code. To do so you need to find a good value of how much to leave at all sides. Those values will depend on all the things you want to show around, including all axes and labels and the legend(s). For 3 CAs you can start with `ca.Position = new ElementsPosition(10, 70, 5, 23);`

Comment: - Hm on 2nd thought this might be avout the size of the InnerPlotAreas. Here the same course of action applies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the chart area alignment options?  I would try something like:

```
//define inner plot position of the chart areas
dlChart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = true;
dlChart.ChartAreas[1].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = true;
dlChart.ChartAreas[2].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = true;

//set our second chart area's alignments to match our first chart area
dlChart.ChartAreas[1].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
dlChart.ChartAreas[1].AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
dlChart.ChartAreas[1].AlignWithChartArea = dlChart.ChartAreas[0].Name;

//set our third chart area's alignments to match our first chart area
dlChart.ChartAreas[2].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
dlChart.ChartAreas[2].AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
dlChart.ChartAreas[2].AlignWithChartArea = dlChart.ChartAreas[0].Name;
```

Comment: Nice! I had forgotten about these Alignments. It works fine, provided one knows which to align with which..

Comment: Thank you @Baddak for your support

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take control of the size of the [`InnerPlotPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.innerplotposition(v=vs.110).aspx).

(But Baddack's solution is simpler and more flexible!)

Here is an example:

After setting up a `Chart` with **three** `CharAreas`, setting `Minima` and `Maxima` as well as adding one `DataPoint` to each we get this :

[image]

Your issue is showing clearly.

After setting the `InnerPlotPosition` to a fixed percentage it looks like this:

[image]

Here is how to set the `InnerPlotPosition` size:

```
ca1.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10, 5, 80, 90);
ca2.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10, 5, 80, 90);
ca3.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10, 5, 80, 90);
```

Note that both `ChartArea.Position` and `ChartArea.InnerPlotPosition` are called 'Position' but really are **areas of percentages** referring to the **respective containers**!

So my example has a `Left` distance of 10%, a `Top` space of 5% and `Width` of 80% and `Height` of 90%. Which leaves 10% space at the `Bottom` and 5% at the `Right`. **Note**: All are referring to the `ChartAreas` not the `ClientArea` of the `Chart`! (Which are still at `Auto`, which maximizes the size.)

This was my initial setup:

```
ChartArea ca1 = chart.ChartAreas[0];
ChartArea ca2 = chart.ChartAreas[1];
ChartArea ca3 = chart.ChartAreas[2];


Series s1 = chart.Series[0];
Series s2 = chart.Series.Add("Series2");
Series s3 = chart.Series.Add("Series3");

s2.ChartArea = ca2.Name;
s3.ChartArea = ca3.Name;

s1.Points.AddXY(1, 7);
s2.Points.AddXY(1, 777);
s3.Points.AddXY(1, Math.PI);
```